# Why string is functioning differently

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code

```
 char ptr=new char();


 int counter = 1;
 string s = new System.String(ptr, counter);

 // does not show something
 MessageBox.Show(s+"Something");

 //shows something
 MessageBox.Show("Something" + s);
```

The first Messagebox shows nothing [image]

The Second Messagebox shows something [image]

If the counter value is 0 then both messagebox shows same result but if counter is greater than 0 then the problem occurs.

I think the problem is with `new  string(ptr, counter)` initilization

. But I want to know the internal mechnism why this is occured.

Comment: What character do you expect `new char()` to return?

Comment: @Cole Johnson: Indeed. I was asking the OP, though :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ptr` is a null character (`'\0'`) and `s` is a `string` with one copy of that character (i.e. `"\0"`). So, at runtime, your first call's parameter evaluates to `"\0Something"` whereas your other one evaluates to `"Something\0"`.

In C#, `string`s are allowed to have null characters; you can conceptualize them as just a `char[]` array (which has a known length); So null characters are OK. The issue comes about when you pass to a C API. C doesn't have strings, so they're immitated using [null-terminated strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string). As far as any C API is concerned, `"\0Something"` is an empty string (`strlen` would return 0). So, when you use `MessageBox.Show`, your string is passed on down to the Win32 API function, [`MessageBoxW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) which only understands null-terminated strings.

---

From the .NET [source code for `MessageBox.Show(string)`](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/67bbe0551b46defdea8ddac62c8aab6130721ed7/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/MessageBox.cs#L138=)

```
public static DialogResult Show(string text)
{
    return ShowCore(null, text, string.Empty, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, 0, false);
}
```

Towards [the end of `ShowCore`](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/67bbe0551b46defdea8ddac62c8aab6130721ed7/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/MessageBox.cs#L394=), we see this line:

```
return (DialogResult)MessageBoxW(handle, text, caption, style);
```

And that `MessageBoxW` call is that Win32 API function in `user32.dll`.

Comment: just FYI: The "1" wouldn't be printed in any case... `new String(char, int)` produces a string made of `char` repeated `int` times e.g. `new String(ptr, 5)` would produce "\0\0\0\0\0". That's why `new String(ptr, 0)` works -- it produces an empty string with no NUL characters. :)

Comment: Wow, what the heck? Strings in C# are null-terminated?

Comment: @SargeBorsch No, but the API that MeassageBox is passing to does check for null terminated strings.

Answer (score 4):

`new char()` returns an empty character (contains two zero bytes), so `ptr` is `'\0'`.

When you use `s = new System.String(ptr, 0);`, the constructor concatenates the `'\0'` character **zero** times, resulting in an empty string (`""`). Adding the empty string to another string has no effect, so `s+"Something"` is equal to `"Something"+s` which is `"Something"`.

In another way, using `s = new System.String(ptr, 1);` creates a string containing a single `'\0'` character. Then adding this string before `"Something"` results in `"\0Something"` where adding after it results in `"Something\0"`.

In C# strings are **not** manipulated as NULL-Terminated Strings, so when you create `"\0Something"`, you really have it (you can make sure by taking the `Length` of the string which is 10), however `MessageBox.Show` is converted to Win32 [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) function of the windows user32 library. And that function requires a null-terminated string (it stops when encounters a zero byte or two zero bytes for unicode strings).